# Dropdown in every row of jquery datatable

Tags: jquery, model-view-controller, datatable

I have 2 tables. `Category(Id, Name)` and `Product(Id, Name, CatgeoryID)`. Now I have to display Product name and category name in the datatable. I am dealing with jquery datatablea and need to fetch category based on product from DB. I understod this part that under `('#myDatatable').Datatable` columns part I will have to create a drop down but how?

Comment: have you tried anything so far

Comment: Can you please show your code, how you binding the data table with Jquery.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this using HTML Table. In the example, I am passing the product and categories through the tuple class

Model

```
public class Category
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}


public class Product
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int CatgeoryID { get; set; }
}
```

Controller

```
// Get the product and category data from the database
var tuple = new Tuple<List<Category>, List<Product>>(categories, products);
return View(tuple);
```

Razor

```
@model Tuple<List<Category>, List<Product>>

<table>
    @foreach (Product item in Model.Item2)
    {
    <tr>
        <td>@item.ID</td>
        <td>@item.Name</td>
        <td>
            @Html.DropDownList("Category",
                        new SelectList(Model.Item1,"ID", "Name", @item.CatgeoryID),
                        "Select Category",
                        new { @class = "form-control" })
            </td>
    </tr>
    }
</table>
```